# Fraction raised to integer power

Tags: exponentiation, irrational-numbers, fractions

if I have $(p/q)^n$ where $p,q,n$ are integers and $p/q$ is a... I don't know what you call it. Not a whole number, but something like 15/7 where you can't reduce it any more and it's non-integer. Can $(p/q)^n$ ever be an integer?

Comment: $p/q$ is called a rational number.  The integers are a subset of the rational numbers.

Comment: @AmireBendjeddou I was hesitant to say rational number since I believe those also include integers, and I know an integer raised to an integer is always an integer. I'm referring to mixed fractions raised to integer powers.

Comment: You could say that you are working in the set of non-integer rationals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is not an integer, there must be some prime which divides the denominator but not the numerator. The same will be true of all integer powers $n\ge 1$, so it cannot be an integer.

Comment: But $(\frac12)^0=1$ and $(\frac12)^{-1}=2$.

Comment: But for positive integer powers?

Answer (score 3):

$(\frac{p}q)^n$ cannot be an integer for $p,q$ and $n$ integers and $n\geq 1$ and $p$ is not divisible by $q$, as in your case. For if $p$ is not divisible by $q$, then so is the case for $p^n$ and $q^n$, hence it cannot be an integer for if you want it to be an integer the denominator must be $\pm 1$, or $q$ must divide $p$. Also it trivially holds for $n=0$. Also for $n<0$ and $p$ does not divide $q$, then $(\frac{p}q)^n$ will be an integer for $p=\pm 1$ and any integer $q \neq 0 $.